# simple angular validation doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, validation

Why doesn't validation  work? It's pretty simple:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="formCtrl" >
    <form name="productForm" ng-submit="addCartItem()" novalidate >
       <input type="text" name="quantity" ng-maxlength="2" required novalidate />
        <span class="error" ng-show="productForm.quantity.$error.required">Required!</span>
        <input id="submitProductForm" type="submit"  />
    </form>
</div>

function formCtrl($scope){
    $scope.addCartItem = function(){
        alert(productForm.$error);
    }
}
```

Here the link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ogwsa5wn/

Comment: take a look at my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have forgot to add `ng-model` to input textfield

just use

```
<input type="text" ng-model="quantity" name="quantity" ng-maxlength="2" required novalidate />
```

instead of

```
<input type="text" name="quantity" ng-maxlength="2" required novalidate />
```

**[Working JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ogwsa5wn/2/)**